# Why don't I have permission to copy to my ext4-formatted external drive?

Tags: filesystem

I have an external drive that is a few years old and now I wanna format it. I dont know what file system I should use with ubuntu. I tried ext4, but it gives me a headache when I am trying to copy documents. It says I dont have the permission to copy files there. I dont really wanna use this hard drive with windows computers...that's why I decided to go for the ext4 file system.

Any ideas why I cant copy or what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reformat the drive using diskutility , And make sure that you cheked 'take the owner ship of the file system' check button

Comment: I'm sure this answer would work, but I for one would love to know why this happens occasionally.

Comment: @tachyons Thanks. This was the problem and now it is all sorted out. :)

Comment: @user407462 : Sorry I am not a linux expert

Answer (score 1):

First run this command in terminal:
sudo nautilus

then go to the partition you want and change permissions to your username in both part of owner and group;)